# Url not changing on clicking on tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3, and clicking on tabs does not update the Url, inspite of using tabUrlPath. Below is the block of code:

```
  <ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top" tabsHighlight="true">
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Details" [root]="details" tabUrlPath="details"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabTitle="Issues" [root]="issues" tabUrlPath="issues"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
```

Any idea, what could be missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean it's not changing tabs?

Comment: @ChesterLaborde no, the tabs change, but the URL is not updated whenever I click on tabs. Isnt that what tabUrlPath is supposed to do?

Answer (score -1):

Did you assign any page component to `details` and `issues` variables?

```
//tabs.ts

import {DetailsPage} from './details/details'
import {IssuesPage} from './issues/issues'

class TabsPage{
    details = DetailsPage; 
    issues = IssuesPage;
    constructor(){
    }

}
```